# Powerbuilder 11.2 has stopped working Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, powerbuilder

I am running and supporting a PowerBuilder 11.2 application running in windows 7 64bit environment.  The previous version of this program ran without a problem, and 99% of this new program runs without a problem.  However, when I run a specific bit of functionality, at times the program throws an exception "Sybase PowerBuilder 11.0 has stopped working"  Problem event name APPCRASH Application Name PB110.EXE, Fault Module Name PBSHR110.dll, Exception code c0000005 in the dev environment.  In the compiled version running on the client machine the error "A breakpoint in an application indicates a program error.  After this dialog is dismissed, the application will continue to run, but it may be in an unstable state" and the program closes

There are shared PBL files throughout this whole application.  It is a framework that supports 6 MDI programs.  I have performed a full build on the main objects and it compiles without error.  The other programs that in the framework that use these common objects to not have this problem.  I have tried to step through the code doing a debug, but when I step through the code, it does not crash.

I have re-installed PB 11.0 and the PB 11.2 upgrade again and of course rebooted numerous times.  I am at a loss here.  I have tried everything that worked before and have spent over a week trying to find something online, so I am now appealing to the group.  Any help at all will be so very much appreciated.  Until then, I'll keep trying.

Thanks.

John

Comment: Exception `c0000005`is "access violation". I.E. the program (currently the module PBSHR110 - like PB SHaRed internal functions) is reading or writing a wrong memory address, usually due to a bad pointer. It can be related to a faulty call to windows API but it can often be fixed by rebuilding the application. Does it continue to crash after a full rebuild of the PB app? Do you know what the application is doing at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that PB 11.2 is not listed as being supported on Windows 7.  A lot of times you can get lucky, and most applications will still work on unsupported OS's.  Yet, an update may be released that breaks something.  You may want to try downloading the latest release of PB which is 12.6 and migrate a copy of your application to that version.  You will at least be able to rule out if that is the issue or not.

> Enclosed is Sybase PowerBuilder Enterprise version 11.2, which is
>   compatible with the following platform and operating system
>   configurations:
>
> ```
> Microsoft Windows XP with Service Pack 2
>
> Microsoft Windows XP Tablet PC Edition with Service Pack 2
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1
>
> Microsoft Windows Vista Business Edition
> ```
>
> PowerBuilder 11.2 builds 32-bit applications, but supports deployed
>   applications in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments on the Vista
>   operating system. For more information about using PowerBuilder on the
>   Vista operating system, see “Vista Support” in the online Help. For a
>   list of issues that have been found on the Vista operating system, see
>   “Vista issues”.
>
> Microsoft Windows 2000 with Service Pack 4 is supported for deployment
>   only. All support for this platform will be discontinued in future
>   releases of PowerBuilder.